# voltage changes on one receptacle

Tags: electrical

The house I am working on only has a 2-wire circuit with metal wall boxes but no grounding. On one receptacle the voltage changes from 115 to 60.

If I turn the breaker off and do some testing for maybe 2-3 minutes, then turn the breaker back on the voltage is 115. It will stay at 115 for about 1 minute then the voltage drops to about 60 and stays there until I turn the breaker off and wait about 3-4 minutes then turn it back on. Then the voltage is 115 again for about 1 minute.

The painter shorted the hot terminals to the metal box and heard a loud pop. My thinking is that the wire burned but not completely apart. Is it possible that the hot side is making contact until power is applied then heats up and does not break completely but gives me the 60-volt reading?

Comment: did you look inside the box, take a picture

Comment: This might help:  If you have two lamps wired in parallel (the correct way) they will each get 120 volts.   If something screws up the wiring and they are wired in series, they will each get 60 volts.

Comment: What happens if you plug in a small incandescent lamp (not CFL or LED). Does it work? Go out or dim eventually? What is the voltage reading with it plugged in?

Comment: As @nobody suggests, measuring voltage **without a load** is meaningless. A length of wire, insulated and unconnected to anything but a high-impedance meter, will pick up AC by capacitance from nearby wires.

Comment: Thanks people I will try some of this when I return to the Job site